# Update/SET a SQL query timestamp when a project is moved from a specific status to another specific one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem where I need to set a timestamp in my database if the user changes some settings in a specific order, I'll give you more details below!

**The database:**

```
#USERS
user_id  user_name  user_password ...
1        Adam       ....
2        Bryan      ....
3        Claire     ....
4        Donna      ....

#PROJECTS
project_id  project_name  project_status  project_start  project_delivery
1           Name 1        Inbox           2018-01-01     2018-01-10         
2           Name 2        Working         2018-01-03     2018-01-12
3           Name 3        Delivered       2018-01-03     2018-01-04
4           Name 4        Delivered       2018-01-04     2018-01-04
```

**The current query:**

```
$query = "

UPDATE projects

SET

project_name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_name'])."',

project_status = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_status'])."',

project_start = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_start'])."',

project_delivery = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_delivery'])."'

WHERE

project_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'

";
```

**The PHP:**

Is basically just a  select/option and input fields. Note that the `project_status` is a select/option one.

**The problem:**

In short, I'd like `project_start` to be updated with todays timestamp when a project is moved from Inbox to Working in `project_status`.

And the same for `project_delivery` when a project is moved from Working to Delivered.

Any ideas on how I could achieve something like this?

Comment: You can use `Case .. when` expressions. It will need some `if..else` at PHP level and MySQL level as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this

```
 SET project_start = CASE
                     WHEN project_status = 'Inbox' THEN CURDATE()
                     ELSE project_start
                     END 
     project_delivery = CASE
                        WHEN project_status = 'Working' THEN CURDATE() 
                        ELSE project_delivery
                        END 
 WHERE   ....
```

Comment: Hey Igor, Thanks for your reply! The answer partly helped me since I now get the project_start and project_delivery to get updated when the status is 'Inbox or 'Working'. However.. I'd only like the update to actually happen when the project status is changed "upward". So when a project is moved from Inbox to Working, I'd like the change to happend. So I'm thinking I need to track the current state from the SQL and the eventually "changed" state in this project edit session. And then based on that data run some simular CASE query as you suggested. Do you have any more ideas?  Thanks in advance